# Android where to add the Button?

Tags: android, button

I have probably invested about 10 hours on this mistake xD still cant find it :/
I have basically 3 layouts. The first layout is for the menu/home, the second is a quiz, and the third is the results screen. The problem right now is that I have no idea how to connect the button from the result screen. (has a button to go back to the menu layout). I dont know where I can add this:

```
Button haupt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hauptmeldung);
haupt.setOnclickListener(this); //this refers to the one in the QuizActivty,
```

abschlusslayout = result screen

activtymain = home/menu layout

quizlayout = quiz

Here are my 3 java files:

MainActivity (QuizActivity):

```
package at.lorenzdirry.philosophenquiz;

import at.lorenzdirry.philosophenquiz.R.id;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizActivity extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
    Spiellogik spiel;
    Button startbut1;
    View myView;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myView = (View)findViewById(id.mainlay);
        startbut1= (Button)findViewById(id.startb1);
        startbut1.setOnClickListener(this);


        spiel = new Spiellogik();


    }
    public View getTheView(){

        return myView;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {


        int id = v.getId();

        if (id == R.id.antwort1)
            spiel.auswerten(1, this); // spielAuswerten(1);
        else if (id == R.id.antwort2)
            spiel.auswerten(2, this); // spielAuswerten(2);
        else if (id == R.id.antwort3)
            spiel.auswerten(3, this); // spielAuswerten(3);
        else if (id == R.id.antwort4)
            spiel.auswerten(4, this); // spielAuswerten(4);
        else if (id == R.id.startb1)
            aufrufen();
        else if (id==R.id.hauptmeldung)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Leider nichts gewonnen.  :-(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }
    View v;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(this.findViewById(id.mainlay)==getTheView()){
            backButtonHandler();

        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuizActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }


    }
    public void backButtonHandler() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                QuizActivity.this);

        alertDialog.setTitle("Beenden");

        alertDialog.setMessage("Sicher Beenden?");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ja",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Nein",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.show();
    }



    public void aufrufen(){
        setContentView(R.layout.quiz_layout);


        for (int n = 1; n <= 4; n++) {
            Button btn = null;

            switch (n) {
                case 1:
                    btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.antwort1);
                    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.antwort2);
                    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.antwort3);
                    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.antwort4);
                    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
                    break;

            }

        }
        spiel.fragen[spiel.aktFrage].anzeigen(this);

    }


    }
```

Frage:

```
package at.lorenzdirry.philosophenquiz;

import at.lorenzdirry.philosophenquiz.R.id;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


class Frage {
    private String frage;
    private String frage2;
    private String frage3;
    private String option1;
    private String option2;
    private String option3;
    private String option4;
    private int loesung;

    public Frage(String f,String f2,String f3, String o1, String o2, String o3, String o4, int l) {
        frage = f;
        frage2 = f2;
        frage3 = f3;
        option1 = o1;
        option2 = o2;
        option3 = o3;
        option4 = o4;
        loesung = l;
    }




    public void anzeigen(Activity quizActivity) {

        ((TextView) quizActivity.findViewById(id.frage)).setText("\u2022 "+frage);
        ((TextView) quizActivity.findViewById(id.frage2)).setText("\u2022 "+frage2);
        ((TextView) quizActivity.findViewById(id.frage3)).setText("\u2022 "+frage3);
        ((Button) quizActivity.findViewById(id.antwort1)).setText(option1);
        ((Button) quizActivity.findViewById(id.antwort2)).setText(option2);
        ((Button) quizActivity.findViewById(id.antwort3)).setText(option3);
        ((Button) quizActivity.findViewById(id.antwort4)).setText(option4);
    }

    public boolean richtig(int ausgewaehlt) {
        if (ausgewaehlt == this.loesung)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Spiellogik:

```
package at.lorenzdirry.philosophenquiz;

import at.lorenzdirry.philosophenquiz.R.id;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;


class Spiellogik{

    final int ANZAHL_FRAGEN = 8;

    Frage[] fragen = new Frage[ANZAHL_FRAGEN];
    Random r = new Random();


    int aktFrage = r.nextInt(ANZAHL_FRAGEN);
    int gewinnstufe = 0;


    Spiellogik() {

        fragen[0] = new Frage("624-546 v.Chr.","Monismus","\"Alles besteht aus Wasser.\"",
                "Thales von Milet", "Aristoteles", "Platon", "Immanuel Kant", 1);
        fragen[1] = new Frage("\u2248600 v.Chr.","Daoismus","\"Wer andere kennt, ist klug. Wer sich selbst kennt, ist weise.\"",
                "Laotse ", "Alkmaion", "Roger Bacon", "Sokrates", 1);
        fragen[2] = new Frage("570-495 v.Chr.","a\u00B2+b\u00B2=c\u00B2","\"Vernunft ist unsterblich, alles andere sterblich.\"",
                "Pythagoras", "Thomas von Aquin", "Archytas von Tarent", "Platon", 1);
        fragen[3] = new Frage("563-483 v.Chr.","Buddhismus","\"Gl\u00fccklich ist, wer sein ich \u00fcberwunden hat.\"",
                "Siddharta Gautama (Buddha)", "Anaximenes", "Antiphon aus Athen", "Kleanthes", 1);
        fragen[4] = new Frage("551-479 v.Chr.","Konfuzianismus","\"Mache Treue und Aufrichtigkeit zu obersten Prinzipien.\"",
                "Konfuzius", "Melissos", "Damaskios", "Panaitios", 1);
        fragen[5] = new Frage("535-475 v.Chr.","Monismus","\"Alles flie\u00dft. (panta rhei)\"",
                "Heraklit", "Pyrrhon", "Proklos", "Theodoros", 1);
        fragen[6] = new Frage("490-420 v.Chr.","Relativismus","\"Der Mensch ist Ma\u00df aller Dinge.\"",
                "Protagoras", "Xenokrates", "Zenon von Sidon", "Jamblichos", 1);
        fragen[7] = new Frage("460-370 v.Chr.","Atomismus","\"In Wirklichkeit gibt es nur die Atome und das Leere.\"",
                "Leukipp", "Epicharmos", "Thales von Milet", "Philolaos", 1);

    }

    void auswerten(int schalter, Activity quizActivity) {

        if (!fragen[aktFrage].richtig(schalter)) {  // falsch beantwortet
            if (gewinnstufe == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(quizActivity, "Leider nichts gewonnen.  :-(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                String str = "Sie haben Gewinnstufe " + gewinnstufe + " erreicht!  :-)  - Glckwunsch!!!";
                Toast.makeText(quizActivity, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // Schalter deaktivieren
            ((Button) quizActivity.findViewById(id.antwort1)).setEnabled(false);
            ((Button) quizActivity.findViewById(id.antwort2)).setEnabled(false);
            ((Button) quizActivity.findViewById(id.antwort3)).setEnabled(false);
            ((Button) quizActivity.findViewById(id.antwort4)).setEnabled(false);

        } else {
            aktFrage= r.nextInt(ANZAHL_FRAGEN);
            if (gewinnstufe < 7) {
                fragen[aktFrage].anzeigen(quizActivity);

                gewinnstufe++;
                ((TextView) quizActivity.findViewById(id.richtigeFragen)).setText("Richtig beantwortete Fragen : "+gewinnstufe+"/8");
                ((ProgressBar) quizActivity.findViewById(id.progressBar1)).setProgress(gewinnstufe);
            }
            else {
                gewinnstufe++;
                ((TextView) quizActivity.findViewById(id.richtigeFragen)).setText("Richtig beantwortete Fragen : " + gewinnstufe + "/8");
                ((ProgressBar) quizActivity.findViewById(id.progressBar1)).setProgress(gewinnstufe);
                quizActivity.setContentView(R.layout.abschluss_layout);


            }
        }
    }



}
```

I hope you can help me, pls :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return on your Menu activity by using a Button :

```
Button yourbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickLIstener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Menu.class));
    }
}
```

Replace all the vars by yours ;)